# How to search for other items in an array in a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

My example array for this problem is:

`fruits = [[apples, oranges], [pears, grapes]]`

How could I find which array `apples` is in (`fruits[0]` or `fruits[1]`) and then show the value for `fruits[0][1]` with this information?

(more explanation if needed)

If I were to have the code:

```
choice = input('Enter a fruit: ')
fruits = [[apples, oranges], [pears, grapes]]
print('The fruit grouped with', choice, 'in the 2D array is', <variable>)
```

How could I change it to produce the output:

```
<< Enter a fruit: apples
>> The fruit grouped with apples in the 2D array is oranges
```

Comment: Is it always pair of two elements in the list or a sublist can also have multiple elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a string is in an list of strings using `in`:

```
'oranges' in ['apples', 'oranges']
# True
```

You can combine this with a list comprehension and a condition to get a list of items where this condition is True:

```
fruits = [['apples', 'oranges'], ['pears', 'grapes']]

# for each group in collection
#            |        |
#            V        V
[group for group in fruits if 'grapes' in group]
#                          |___________________| 
#                               | 
# give me that group if the condition is true 

# It's results in a list of lists because there could be more than one
# [['pears', 'grapes']]
```

If you know there will only be one, you can ask for the `next` one. Passing `None` as a second argument give a default. You could also put something like an empty list there if it makes more sense for your problem:

```
fruits = [['apples', 'oranges'], ['pears', 'grapes']]

choice = 'pears'
next((group for group in fruits if choice in group), None)
# ['pears', 'grapes']

choice = 'oranges'
next((group for group in fruits if choice in group), None)
# ['apples', 'oranges']

choice = 'bannanas'
next((group for group in fruits if choice in group), None)
 # None
```

Comment: Thank you! this perfectly solves my problem